# Failed to Authenticate HTTPS connection when attempting GET from WebAPI

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I am using ASP.NET Core. I have two projects:

1. ASP.NET Core MVC application
2. ASP.NET Core Web API application

If I attempt to access one of the Web API endpoints using Postman, I do not have any issues; the `/api/values` endpoint returns as expected. (This is the standard test endpoint.)

If I attempt the same operation using the MVC application, however, I get a very frustrating error:

```
HttpsConnectionFilter[1]
Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection
```

I am hosting using Kestrel for ASP.NET Core.

I have a self-signed PFX certificate I created using PowerShell, and this is the code throwing the exception:

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("localcert.pfx", "xxx"));
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44301/api/values");
```

And I get the same error if I were to run this:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44301/api/values");
```

My Kestrel setup is like so in my `Program.cs`:

```cs
var cert = new X509Certificate2("localcert.pfx", "xxx");

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseKestrel(cfg => cfg.UseHttps(cert))
  .UseUrls("https://localhost:44300")
  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .UseIISIntegration()
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build();

host.Run();
```

I know I defined the certificate again for the `HttpClient` above, but I am desperate.

Can anyone offer some insight as to why this is happening and how I can go about fixing it, or even debugging it? I am currently in the process of stepping through the `KestrelHttpServer` code to see if that will offer some insight.

This is the full error I get from the Kestrel console window:

> info: HttpsConnectionFilter[1](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/pull/1017/files)
>         Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection. System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the
>   transport stream.    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.d__6.MoveNext()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The most straight forward solution I found for this problem was to remove the cert and add it with the trust flag.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

PS. I know this is old but I am just going to leave this here for someone that might stumble to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. After many hours of checking everything possible and even some impossible stuff, I managed to trace it back to wrongly generated SSL certificate.

I was creating mine according to this manual: [How to: Create Your Own Test Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx).

The certificate is generated using this command:

```
makecert -sv yourprivatekeyfile.pvk -n "cert name" yourcertfile.cer -r
```

where if `-r` is omitted, described error occurs.

Then `pfx` must be generated according to the manual. If one uses just `cer`, `Kestrel` will not start successfully.

I solved it by generating a new SSL certificate.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I will try this evening and hopefully share your success :)

Comment: I've still got the same issue, creating a certificate from PowerShell like here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/29/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/

Comment: makecert has been deprecated, and we should use powershell commandlet New-SelfSignedCertificate

Comment: this is usefull too:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/25701/stack-trace-systemioioexception-authentication-fai.html